# docker install error

Tags: docker

I write this command

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

to install docker but it gave me this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
E: Unable to locate package docker-buildx-plugin
E: Unable to locate package docker-compose-plugin
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker is available through their own repository, which you must first enable for your package management system.

Follow these steps to get it safely installed:

1. Install prerequisite packages

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
```

2. Add Docker's GPG key

```
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

3. Setup the repository

```
echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

4. Install the engine and other goodies

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

You can verify the installation by issuing the following command:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

The instructions were copied from the following website, that has more details and other relevant information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/